# Algebraic Proof help with real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct non-zero real numbers

Show that $-\frac{4ab}{(a-b)^2} = 1 - (\frac{a+b}{a-b})^2$

It's been 15 years since I have been in high school but I came across this problem and wanted to solve it.

$-\frac{4ab}{(a-b)^2} = -\frac{4ab}{a^2+b^2-2ab}$

And now I am stuck I assume I have to split this fraction up but I can't remember how to d that correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, in general, fractions are annoying so my first piece of advice would be to simplify by multiplying through by $(a-b)^2$ on both sides. Cheers

Comment: Fully expand both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that

$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\tag{1}$$(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2\tag{2}$

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$
$$4ab=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$$

$$\begin{align}-\dfrac{4ab}{(a-b)^2}&=-\dfrac{(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2}{(a-b)^2}\\&=-\left(\dfrac{a+b}{a-b}\right)+\dfrac{(a-b)^2}{(a-b)^2}\\&=1-\left(\dfrac{a+b}{a-b}\right)^2\qquad\blacksquare\quad\text{Q.E.D}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$ and
$a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$ are popular identities.

Reexpressing the numerator as follows should help:
$-4ab=-2ab+-2ab=a^2-2ab+b^2-(a^2+2ab+b^2)=(a-b)^2-(a+b)^2$

Let me know if I need to add more.